# Angular autocomplete unable to select unexisting values

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-material, autocomplete

I develop a web app (Angular, Typescript) managing "missions". For each mission I would like to add tags to it with a form. I have created an angular form to add tags to the mission which suggests me already existing tags to avoid that users create redundancies in the database by entering several times the same tag with just a slight syntax difference.
It works pretty well : when I write the beginning of an already existing tag, it suggests it to me, I can select it and ok ! But the problem is when I write then select an unexisting tag, not suggested. The form returns me an undefined value whereas I would like to get my new tag name as response (I will then add it to the TagModel).
Here is my code :

**Dialog-add-tag.component.ts**

```
export class DialogAddTagComponent implements OnInit {
    formGroup: FormGroup;

    tagFormControl: FormControl;

    tagOptions: Observable <TagGetAllResponseInterface>;

    displayFunction (key: {name: string}): string {
        if (key === null) {
            return null;
        }
        return `${key.name}`;
    }

    constructor (
        public tagService: TagService,
        public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private readonly dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogAddTagComponent>
    ) { }

    ngOnInit (): void {
        this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            tag: this.tagFormControl
        });
        this.tagFormControl = new FormControl(
            null,
            [Validators.required.bind(this)]);
        this.tagOptions = this.tagFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
            debounceTime(100),
            switchMap(value => from(this.tagService.getAll(25, 0, value)))
        );
    }

    onSelect (): void {
        this.dialogRef.close({name: this.tagFormControl.value.name});
    }
}
```

**Dialog-add-tag.component.html**

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add a tag</h2>

<form id="form-container" class="mat-typography container" [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="tagFormControl">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFunction">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of (tagOptions | async)?.tags" [value]="tag">
                {{tag.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button mat-raised-button
            color="primary"
            class="full-width-button margin-top-button"
            [disabled]="tagFormControl.invalid"
            (click)="onSelect()"
    >Select</button>
</form>
```

**Tag.interface.ts**

```
export interface TagGetAllResponseInterface {
    tags: {
        name: string;
    }[];
}

export interface TagGetAllRequestInterface {
    limit: string;
    page: string;
    search?: string;
}
```

I think that the issue comes from the :

```
switchMap(value => from(this.tagService.getAll(25, 0, value))
```

which returns null when the tag doesn't exist. So what do I have to add to make that when I click on Select, it selects the tag written in the form, even if it doesn't exist in the database ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option is to make the tagService.getAll() function return the given value if there aren't any matches in the list.

So if the function searches in its list and does not find any match it should return the original value (the one that is written in the form)

Comment: Hey, thank you : adding a condition to return the original value when the search does not find any match worked for me !

Comment: Hi @Manuel what you suggest is a UX rule or just code imporvement?